# Hypergraph vertex plus incident edge deletion giving isomorphic subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

There exist hypergraphs $H = (V, E)$ such that upon the deletion of any arbitrary vertex $v \in V$ and any edge $e \in E$ that is incident to $v$ (along with all vertices in $e$), one obtains the same subgraph $G$. An example is the $n \times n$ grid-hypergraph $H$, i.e.,  a family of sets $\{A_1, \dots, A_n, B_1, \dots, B_n\}$ such that $|A_i| = |B_i| = n$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, $A_i \cap A_j = B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ and $|A_i \cap B_j| = 1$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq n$, for which the deletion of any vertex and edges incident to the vertex (along with all vertices in those edges) gives rise to the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ grid-hypergraph $G$.

I would like to know if there is a characterisation of the hypergraphs $G$ that can be $\textit{lifted}$ to a hypergraph $H$ with this property. Can only grid hypergraphs be lifted in such a manner?

Comment: Your definition of the grid hypergraph is not complete, as it describes more than one graphs. You could have vertices that belongs to only one hyperedge. If we fix our definition of the grid hypergraph with the requirement hat the graphs have $n^2$ vertices (so each vertex belongs to exatly two hyperedges), then  when deleting a vertex of your $n\times n$-grid, you don't get a $n-1\times n-1 grid. That's because you  still have too much vertices (some of these belongs to only one hyperedge).

Comment: Yes, we impose the requirement that the graph has $n^2$ vertices so that each vertex belongs to exactly two hyperedges. The operation is to delete a vertex and all edges incident to the vertex. So that deleting a vertex of the $n \times n$ grid and all edges incident to the vertex produces an $n-1 \times n-1$ grid.

Comment: As it is stated, the deletion of one vertex removes only one vertex of the graphs, so de leting a vertex of a $n \times n$ grid does not produce a $n-1 \times n-1$ grid (because you still have $n^2 -1$ vertices, which is more than $(n-1)^2$ vertices.

Comment: Ah thanks. Edited the question to reflect that one should delete all vertices in the edges incident to $v$ as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "lifted" in the last paragraph?

Comment: All vertex-deleted hypergraphs  of a transitive hypergraph are isomorphics. The converse is true at least for finite graphs. It is probably the same for hypergraphs with your definition of vertex deletion, but I need to check that.

Comment: By a "lifting" of hypergraph $G$, I just mean a hypergraph $H$ for which every subgraph obtained by this particular vertex deletion operation is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: When deleting vertices neighbors to the deleted vertex, do we agree that if an hyperedge  links only a subset of the neighbors, then this edge is deleted (as it links no more vertex). Do we keep the 1-hyperedges (self loops) ? Do we consider multihypergraphs (When some vertices are deleted, some edges can become equal, so de we need to merge them or keep them distinct) ?

Comment: Yes, if a hyper edge connects only a subset of the neighbours, then that edge must be deleted since there are no vertices that it is incident to. Once a neighbouring vertex is deleted, any self-loops on that vertex is also deleted. We don't consider multihypergraphs but if we would, we would merge the edges that become equal.

Answer (score 2):

Any vertex-transitive hypergraph has this property. For any vertices $v,w$ there is an automorphism taking $v$ to $w$; when we do the vertex-plus-neighbor deletion from $v$ and from $w$, the automorphism becomes an isomorphism between the remainders.

There are plenty of non-grid examples of hypergraphs that could be "left over" from a vertex-transitive graph. For example, you can take a cycle hypergraph (loose or tight or anything in between) and be left with the same path hypergraph after you delete any vertex and all its neighbors.

There are also examples of hypergraphs with this property that aren't vertex transitive - for example, any hypergraph in which every two vertices are on a hyperedge together, because then we're left with nothing when we delete a vertex and all its neighbors. But I don't know if there's anything here that gives us new examples of "left over" graphs, other than the null graph.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to see that any vertex-transitive hypergraph $G$ has such a "lifting" or extension to a bigger hypergraph $H$ for which this vertex deletion operation always gives rise to $G$ irrespective of which vertex is deleted?

Comment: Vertex-transitive characterizes the bigger graphs, not the smaller ones. It's tricky to characterize the smaller graphs you get after you delete stuff from a bigger vertex transitive graph.